# Question about interesting topics for research

Tags: classical-mechanics, education

I’m college student and I have to write a paper related with physics and math. I would like to have some interesting ideas of not so complex topics to investigate. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve 1-d diffusion equation

$$
\frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 n(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
$$

for $0 \le x \le L$ with initial distribution $n(x,0) = \delta(x-L/2)$.

You may investigate the effect of boundary conditions:

1. two reflection boundaries
   $$
     \frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial x} \big ]_{x=0} = \frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial x} \big ]_{x=L} = 0.
   $$
2. two absorption boundaries
   $$
     n(0, t) = n(L, t) = 0
   $$
3. One reflection boundary and one absorption boundary
   $$
    \frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial x} \big ]_{x=0} = 0; \text{ and } n(L, t) = 0.
   $$

Finally, you may look into partial absorption boundary, if you want to move further.

This can be solve either numerically or analytically (in a fast convergent summation serious). I think this a very heuristic physic exercise with a good math content.